Front door uneven at bottom
There’s a gap at the bottom and the top handle side of our front entry door. We have to push the door a little to get it to close. We’ve already made sure the frame and thresholds are level and replaced the screws so we’re at a loss. How can we fix this?







Is the door square?  Did you replace with longer screws?

Two initial points:

Measurements off the floor mean nothing. It's as likely that the floor is out of level or that the door is tilted as that it shows something significant.

A threshold shouldn't be leveled to solve this problem. Or ever. It should be fit to the door for a good seal. It would be nice if it was also level, but that's a distant second priority.


First, I see a tapered reveal in the jamb over the top hinge. This usually means that there were no screws run through the hinge into framing. Over time the connection to the casing has shifted and any nails into framing have slipped, allowing the jamb to move (not the hinge). You want to rectify that.
Notice how the gap at the top is larger than below. I might even be seeing evidence in the stain line.

That's where I'd start. Get some 3" flathead screws. Pilot about half the screw diameter at a very slight angle toward the center of the wall through one of the hinge holes further toward the center of the wall. Run a screw in there and slowly snug it until things start to move.
Now close the door and check the gap on the top and latch side. They should start to get more parallel and square. If you find that things aren't moving, you may need to remove the interior casing so you can also shim the top corner back in the right direction. Do this in line with the head jamb, not down the side.
Once that's done, and the door is operating well, add another screw in the bottom hinge, but don't tighten that one. Just barely set it snug. It'll help keep things stable.
Now adjust the threshold so it lightly contacts the door bottom all the way across.

we did what you said and it worked fantastically. The door is opening much better. How do we adjust the threshold? We’re going to buy a new one since the weather stripping on this one is gone but we want to make sure we can adjust it properly. Do we just shim underneath it?

Glad to hear it. Please don't ask new questions in comments. I don't have enough information to answer. Post up a new one.

Doors sag, it's pretty normal. Replacing the screws won't do anything unless the original screws had loosened and the new ones are put in more tightly, and that would be solved by just tightening the original screws in that case.
In this case it appears that the lower hinge needs to be shimmed slightly, or the top hinge mortise needs to be cut slightly deeper, to pivot the door very slightly in the frame so it will close easily.
In some cases the joinery of the door itself is such that the parts shift and the door is no longer rectangular - at which point shimming the hinges may lead to binding the vertical edge of the door on the latch-side frame. Not clear that this is happening here, but if it does, you either need to take the door off and trim it back to square, or rack it back and re-glue it (or just replace it.) If the diagonals are not the same length, the door is not a rectangle any more.

Would we just take a chisel to the top mortise? Last time we tried slightly shimming the bottom hinge with cardboard the door wouldn’t close

@ChristopherTaylor Google hinge shims.

I suspect that your door is no longer square.  Look at your first, second, and fourth photos.  You can see a sizeable gap between the bottom rail and the vertical stiles.  Compare that to your last photo, where the top of the door shows seams that are nice and tight.  It's possible that your door is currently a trapezoid shape, wider at the bottom than the top.  That's going to make it hard to get a good, proper close regardless of what else is going on.
Try taking the door off and laying it horizontal.  See if you can get any sort of movement when you squeeze the stiles towards each other.  If they move at all, put some wood glue in the joints, squeeze the stiles together as far as they'll go, and use ropes or a giant clamp to hold it in place until the glue sets.  You can further reinforce the door by drilling a pocket hole on the bottom edge of the door and screwing the stile to the bottom rail (it shouldn't ever be visible so it doesn't have to be pretty).

This could also be true, but I can't discern any skew in the photo of the upper part of the door. I'd expect to see similar gaps and marks on the inset panels. It's worth checking, though.

I live in a 1909 craftsman and not a well constructed one. Over 35 years I have developed a rapport with my house and redefined the term "average level. While installing new windows I found that one of the inexpensive self leveling (green) lasers, available almost everywhere on-line (Amazon, eBay) for around $50 is your best tool for determining what is actually level and square in relation to the jamb and sill. From what I could see from your photos, It appears that your door jamb might actually be a trapezoidal rectangle. In other words, the right and left door jam may be parallel but might not be vertical and square with the sill and top jamb. The top and sill are parallel with each other (and level) but not square with the sides. This can happen with older houses over time. A laser with a horizontal and vertical beam will quickly give you a true indication of where the problem is.
If the sill is level you will likely need to reshim the frame by removing the trim on one side of the hinge side and adding wedge shims at the top or bottom of the jamb. I usually take out the short hinge screws and replace them with long screws that go through the hinge holes and sink firmly into the stud behind the jamb. If the door isn't out of square with the sill much, you might not need to reshim the door knob side and can adjust the trim using a block of wood and a hammer and gently tapping the side of the trim to realign it with the frame. I find that long finish nail screws applied to the upper or lower corners of the door jamb/frame will hold the frame in the correct position if the adjustment is slight. If the adjustment is large, you might need to also remove the trim on the knod side as well. A low expansion door/window foam is also great for fixing things in place before you reinstall the trim. The foam also makes for a solid but flexible shim giving you a solid door feel. You can also put long screws into the door knob latch to adjust the locking bolt plate, giving you a consistent gap on the knob side. Checking everything with the laser level will give you a perfectly aligned and square door and they are handy to have around. I mount mine on an old camera tripod for easy adjustment. Also, they are great for other household chores like hanging pictures and such.
